# Recursive Mysql Query using Joomla Database Object

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, joomla

Hello im trying to fectch all childs and sub childs of a record in db
so far i've got this

```
function fetchNetChildren($parent, $network) {
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery('SELECT id FROM #__sometable_clients WHERE network_referal = '.$parent.' AND networks = '.$network.' AND `status` > 0');
    $list = array();
    while (true){
        $row = $db->loadAssocList();
        $list[] = $row['id'];
        $list = array_merge($list, fetchNetChildren($row['id'], $network));
    }
    return $list;
}
```

when i run this ive got a 500 eror and have no idea why, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Ive achieved this using a different aproach, ive discarded the initial funcion and created 2 others that returns what i want.

1 - I've created a mysql query that returns in a multidimensional array of all childrens, grandchildrens etc of the provided id.

```
function getChilds($parentid, $network) {
    // query linda e maravilhosa
    $query = '
    select @pv:=id as id, network_referal from #__mytable
    join
    (select @pv:='.$parentid.')tmp
    where network_referal=@pv and networks = '.$network.' ';
    $campos = carregarcampos($query,'list');
    return $campos;
}
```

2 - WIth the data $elements now i can manipulate and create a php multidimentional array organizing the provided data

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

so to use i must run

```
buildTree(getChilds($parentid, $network), $parentid)
```